# Form-groups side by side with display: inline-block; working with Firefox not with Chrome

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, input

I am using `display: inline-block;` to have multiple form-group side by side, it's working with Firefox but not with Chrome.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group dis-inl-blc mar-l-20">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">50x25cm :</span>
        <span class="value">Black</span>
    </div> 
</div>
<div class="form-group dis-inl-blc mar-l-20">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">50x40cm :</span>
        <span class="value">Grey, White /  Black /  Gold, Bronze</span>
    </div> 
</div>
<div class="form-group dis-inl-blc mar-l-20">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">50x50cm :</span>
        <span class="value">Gold, Bronze</span>
    </div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dis-inl-blc {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.value {
      display:inline-block;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    height:30px;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}
.mar-l-20 {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8osL6xhf/

How to make these multiples form-group side by side with with Chrome too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try changing the display property to inline-table.

Try this below code.

css

```
.dis-inl-blc {
  display: inline-table;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

hope this works..